# How to print a one dimensional array in an entire excel column without looping?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, printing, range

I have a big one-dimensional array that contains some numbers that I'd like to print in an entire excel column in one go.

This is my code:

```
Sub writeTimeDiff()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim diffArr() As Variant

    lastRow = Sheets("AUX").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    ReDim diffArr(lastRow)

    j = 2

    For i = 0 To lastRow
        'Store the difference between two values in a row in the array
        tsIN = Sheets("AUX").Cells(j, 3).value
        tsOUT = Sheets("AUX").Cells(j, 4).value
        diffArr(i) = tsOUT - tsIN
        j = j + 1
    Next i

    'I'd like it to print the array throughout the entire F column (Starting in F2) 
    Sheets("AUX").Range("F2:F" & lastRow).value = diffArr
End Sub
```

But it seems it is only printing the first value of the array:

[image: 1]

This is what I actually need:

[image: 2]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can easily modify the code in your other question about this data to create the same output (add those columns to the existing columns)

Comment: Yea, I managed to get that, thank you so much for your help, thanks to you I will be able to get my assignment done in time!

Comment: Did you see the edits I made to take care of the errors you were getting?  Did they work?

Comment: Yes they did, I also read a bit of those class guides you posted which helped me have a better understanding of your code in general. Once again, thank you

Comment: Perhaps you could mark that answer of mine as accepted, then.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a 1-dimensional array is treated as a row so you need to transpose it to convert to a column.

```
Sheets("AUX").Range("F2:F" & lastRow).Value = Application.Transpose(diffArr)
```